# 'rnoaa' not pulling monitors for weather stations found

Tags: rnoaa, weatherdata

I have been using the 'rnoaa' package to pull weather data from weather monitors within 30 km of my defined longitude and latitude using the following code which works for the majority of my locations.

```
station_data <- ghcnd_stations()

lat_lon_df_ash <- data.frame(id = "Ashworth",
                             latitude = 53.6377,
                             longitude = -2.2604)

nearby_stations_ash <-  meteo_nearby_stations(lat_lon_df = lat_lon_df_ash,
                                              station_data = station_data, 
                                              var = "all",
                                              year_min = 2013,
                                              year_max = 2023,
                                              radius = 30) #km


weather_data_ash <- meteo_pull_monitors(nearby_stations_ash,
                                        keep_flags = TRUE,
                                        date_min = "2013-01-01",
                                        date_max = "2023-07-20",
                                        var = "all")
```

I get this error for this location:

> Warning message:
> In meteo_pull_monitors(nearby_stations_ash, keep_flags = TRUE, date_min = "2013-01-01",  :
> The following stations could not be pulled from the GHCN ftp:
> list(id = character(0), name = character(0), latitude = numeric(0), longitude = numeric(0), distance = numeric(0))
> Any other monitors were successfully pulled from GHCN.

Why am I getting this error and what does it mean please?

Many thanks!